# ServiceStack Custom ISession/Factory without cookies

Tags: servicestack

I don't use ServiceStack authentication (I have a service that returns a security token).  Also, to authenticate (and keep track of) a session I require secure requests to provide that security token to reference the session in the `Authorisation` Http Header.

I implemented and registered `ISession` and `ISessionFactory` and called `Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());` to disable use of authentication.

Problem is I don't understand how cookies come into play.  My service class inherits from `Service` and have the IOC'd session and `sessionfactory` set, but the session id is already set to what looks to be the cookie.  I would have thought my custom session would be responsible for generating/providing the session key.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Reading a bit more it looks like I would have to (somehow) replace SessionFeature, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the [Session wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) to understand how ServiceStack's Sessions work.

Basically when you register the `Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature())` ServiceStack already creates the `ss-id/ss-pid` cookies for the client.

The cookies are automatically set when using a browser or re-using the same ServiceClient. These cookies are used to access the dynamic / typed user sessions in ServiceStack.

Comment: Is there a way to set the "requires SSL" flag on the cookie?